# SQL: Format Numbers to Display as 4-Digits

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Working with multiple data tables in GBQ that all display the common ID_NUM, which are all four-digit numbers. However in one table, they do not include leading 0's, meaning that my tables look like this:

```
---------------------------------------
|  TABLE A    |   TABLE B  |  TABLE C  |
---------------------------------------
|    0111     |    0111    |    111    |
----------------------------------------
|    0112     |    0112    |    112    |
----------------------------------------
|    0234     |    0234    |    234    |
----------------------------------------
|    1215     |    1215    |    1215   |
----------------------------------------
|    5665     |    5665    |    5665   |
----------------------------------------
```

When I'm trying to combine the data and filter on specific ID_NUM values, filtering on '0111' will not pull back results where '111' is the ID_NUM in Table C.

I've attempted to use `FORMAT(ID_NUM, 0000)` but it results in too many arguments, and I'm not sure what is triggering that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `safe_cast()`:

```
where safe_cast(id_num as int64) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below options:

**Integer Value:**

```
SELECT FORMAT("%04d", 111);
```

**String Value:**

```
SELECT LPAD('111', 4, '0');
```